# Converting string into condition for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a condition for a pandas dataframe written in a string. Something like this:

```
"(data['Variable1'] == 1) & (data['Variable2'] == 2)"
```

Is there a way to apply this condition without using eval() function?

Expected result:

```
data = data[(data['Variable1'] == 1) & (data['Variable2'] == 2)]
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, this looks like a perfect usecase for eval, what's the reason you're not using it?

Comment: eval works fine on a normal script but i have an error when using eval() within an imported module of my main script.

And i honestly don't know why that happens..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pandas [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter required rows

```
your_query_string = "Variable1 == 1 & Variable2 == 2"
data = data.query(your_query_string)
```